# Multilevel models to mitigate asymmetric influences on posterior?

Tags: regression, bayesian, binomial-distribution, experiment-design, multilevel-analysis

I’ve designed an experiment where I would like to evaluate how treatment exposure influences a binary outcome.

We noticed that there was bias between test and control groups in terms of the success rate. So we included a “calibration period” or logs of successes and failures from individuals from both group prior to exposure administration.

So logistic regression was used with two slopes: treatment group assignment and exposure administration. Control would have X=(0,0), treatment group in calibration period would have X=(1,0) and treatment group with exposure would have X=(1,1).

One issue we found is that not all individuals contribute the same number of trails. Consider testing the efficiency of an energy drink on runners; some runners simply go on more runs. In consequence, these individuals seem to have greater influence on the model coefficients and intercept than others.

I’ve read that using a multilevel model could mitigate the effects of unbalanced trials across individuals.

Could someone explain why this is intuitive?